# Own Private traffic tunneling using vps

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Services like WTFAST and other "traffic tunneling" services run over a server, but how exactly they do that? Using SOCKS Tunnel? SSH tunneling?

Is that possible to replicate services like that using a linux vps server?

Comment: Most of these servers support many incoming protocols. If you study the article of [Wikipedia VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) and some of its links, you would understand it better. Or are you asking us to summarize the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no easy way to find out what specifically WTFast uses, but all they say is "intelligent proxy network".
2. There are many ways to tunnel traffic over a server. However, it will rarely, if ever, increase your speeds, but it can be useful for other reasons. Here are some ways to tunnel traffic:

   - OpenVPN: Tunnels all traffic. Most Linux distributions, and many routers, have support for it.
   - SSH Tunnels: Tunnels TCP traffic. Works on any SSH server not specifically configured to deny it. On the client side, just run `ssh [server] -D1080` and point your browser at `127.0.0.1:1080` as a 
     SOCKS proxy.